# Definition of an image of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have the following definition of an image of a linear transformation, but I think that there's a mistake in the size of the field (confusion between `m` and `n`).
$$\begin{align*}
& A\in M_{m \times n}(\mathbb{F})\\
& T:\mathbb{F}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{F}^m \\
& T(v) = A\cdot v
\end{align*}$$
$$v = \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 \\
\vdots \\
\lambda_n
\end{pmatrix},\quad\quad
A = \begin{pmatrix}
\mid & & \mid \\
 u_1 & \ldots & u_n \\
\mid & & \mid
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$
\begin{align*}
ImT &= \left\{w\in W \mid \exists v\in V \;.\; w=T(v)\right\} = \\
 &= \left\{w\in W \mid \exists v\in V \;.\; w=A\cdot v\right\} = \\
 &= \left\{w\in W \mid \text{ w is a linear combination of } u_1,\ldots,u_n\in \mathbb{F}^m \right\} = \\
 &= sp\left\{ u_1,\ldots,u_n\right\} = C(A)
\end{align*}
$$

1. Notice in "w is a linear ...". Should it be a linear combination of $u_1,\ldots,u_n\in \mathbb{F}^n$?
2. Shouldn't the transformation be $T:\mathbb{F}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{F}^n$ instead of $T:\mathbb{F}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{F}^m$ ?

Comment: What is $W$? $\;$

Comment: @goblin: It's not written in my notebook but I'm certain that $ImT \subseteq W$ while $\mathbb{F}^m = W$

Comment: Okay, as far as I can see, all of the definitions and equalities are correct. There is no confusion of $m$ and $n$ that I can see. Try to keep in mind that linear transformations $\mathbb{F}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^m$ are essentially the same as $m \times n$ matrices; so, there's a "flip" that goes on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider $$A = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \end{pmatrix},$$ here $m=2$ and $n=3$. To be able to multiply $A$ by some vector $v$, the vector should be taken from $\mathbb{F}^3$. In other words,
$$v=\begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \end{pmatrix}$$ and the result $A \cdot v$ is a vector from $\mathbb{F}^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Re 1.: No the map's image is part of $\mathbb{F}^m$.

Re 2.: Review how matrix multiplication is done:
$$
w = A v \iff w_i = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} v_j \quad (i \in \{1, \ldots, m \})
$$
It is kind of mathematician's karate, the column vector $v$ gets multiplicated with the $i$-th row vector from $A$ to yield the component $w_i$.
$$
m\left\{
\left(
\begin{matrix}
\vdots \\
w_i \\
\vdots
\end{matrix}
\right)
\right.
=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
* & \cdots & * \\
a_{i1} & \cdots & a_{in} \\
* & \cdots & *
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
v_1 \\
\vdots \\
v_n
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$